# Javascript on a checkbox is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following trivial page:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function check(){  
        var cb = document.getElementById('aaa');  
        if(!cb.checked()){  
            alert("test!!!");  
        }  
    }  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<input id="aaa" type="checkbox" name="modify" onclick="check()">Modify</input>  
</body>  
</html>
```

If I press the check box I see the following error in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'checked' of object #<HTMLInputElement> is not a function  
check   
onclick
```

I also tried with `documents.getElementsByName('modify')` and the same problem.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`checked` isn't a function, as the error message states.

Use

```
if(!cb.checked){
```

(without the parenthesis)

Note that you don't have to look for the element using `getElementById`, you can pass the element :

```
<input id="aaa" type="checkbox" name="modify" onclick="check(this)">Modify  

function check(cb){  
    if(!cb.checked()){  
        alert("test!!!");  
    }  
}
```

Note also that the `input` element should not be closed. What you probably need here is the label `element`, which lets you click on the text to (un)check the box :

```
 <input id="aaa" type="checkbox" name="modify" onclick="check(this)">
 <label for=aaa>Modify</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the brackets from cb.checked() - it is not a function.
This code should work:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function check(){  
        var cb = document.getElementById('aaa');  
        if(!cb.checked){  
            alert("test!!!");  
        }  
    }  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<input id="aaa" type="checkbox" name="modify" onclick="check()">Modify</input>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you think this answer is useless as it's the same than an older one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jquery also and you wrongly added end tag for `input type`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aaa').click (function ()
    {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
    // Do stuff
    alert("test!!!");
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
    <input id="aaa" type="checkbox" name="modify"  />
```